# Get dropdown selected Text from "This" inside JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several drop downs in my page. on page load, I need to pull all the selected texts from the drop downs and do something. I have used this function to pull the selected text:

```
$(window).load(function() {
      $("select").each(function() {

      //get the selected texts here             
      alert($(this).text()); 
      });
});
```

But this function pulls up all the values in the drop downs (not just the selected ones). How can I get only the selected text? I found 'option: selected' in web but how to use it along with $(this) selector? Please help.

Comment: As user Amit Joki suggested you could restrict your line `$("select").each(function() ` to only selected options.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` with `option:selected`:

```
$(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$("select :selected").each(function() {
      //get the selected texts here             
  alert($(this).text()); 
});
```

Comment: @Archer, yeah. Other answers kinda confused me ;) Thanks BTW

Answer (score 1):

If it's a multiselect or you want to get all selected options of all dropdowns on the page, then you can iterate over `select > option:selected`.

```
  $("select > option:selected").each(function() {

      //get the selected texts here             
      alert($(this).text()); 
  });
```

For standard select with one possible selected option just grab:

```
 var selectedText = $("select > option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code didn't work was because in your selector you did not indicate you wanted to retrieve all selected elements. This can be done with [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/).

Here's an example:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // Iterate through all selected elements
    $("select :selected").each(function(index) {    
        // Get the selected texts here
        alert("Item: " + index + " - Value: " + $(this).text()); 
        // Or just alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Look up:

- [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)